# How to filter rows based on length in data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
id      name            cost    
A       first           19
A       ssdecond        22
A       thirdoth        10
```

I can chose columns based on value by

```
df[df.cost > 10]
```

But, how would I do it based on length,

```
df[len(df.name) < 4]
```

I get an error. Is there another way to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select Pandas.DataFrame by elements' length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32440798/1278112)

Answer (score 2):

By using `str.len`

```
df[df.name.str.len() < 6] 
Out[1037]: 
  id   name  cost
0  A  first    19
```

Or using `apply`

```
df[df.name.apply(len)<6]
Out[1040]: 
  id   name  cost
0  A  first    19
```

Answer (score 1):

For filtering the rows, yo can also use **df.loc[]**

```
df.loc[df['name'].str.len()<6]
```